# Automapper Explicit Expansion and Default Values

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2, automapper

With Automapper, you can set a property to require [explicit expansion](http://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Queryable-Extensions.html#explicit-expansion). With this option, if the query does not explicitly request this property to be expanded, Automapper will not map the field and it will be null.

What I am looking for is a way to provide a default value in this case. Specifically, when this option is applied to a property representing a collection, if not expanded, instead of returning null I'd like to return a list of the key identifier(s).

Automapper does provide some functionality for setting [default values](http://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Null-substitution.html), but it appears to only support static values. In this case, that would not work since the collection of data is not known until requested.

Also, I am using dynamic as the target type, so the difference between an array of int's versus an array of complex objects should not be a problem, I think...

Quick example of what I'm trying to achieve, with Members requiring Explicit Expansion

```
GET: www.myapi.com/goups/3?$expand=members   returns-
{
  "id": 3,
  "name":"GroupA",
  "members": [
    { "id":1, "name":"Bob" },
    { "id":2, "name":"Sue" }
  ]
}

GET: www.myapi.com/goups/3   returns-
{
  "id": 3,
  "name":"GroupA",
  "members": [1,2]
}
```

Comment: Do it in two steps, with two different maps, one with explicit expansion, and the second with the defaults.

Comment: That is a logical approach, but it's execution eludes me. I'm using IQueryables with ProjectTo, so I'm not sure how to test for expanded members. The expanded members don't seem to be available in the context, so I can't test for them there. I also can't test for null, because the query has not yet been executed, and not all null members are also expandable. Looking at the source, it looks like the list of members to expand is used to directly modify the expression for the queryable, so maybe I could do something with the expression, perhaps after projection? Not very experienced in that area.

Comment: You would have to materialize the results of the query and then check for null. Otherwise, you'd have to forget about explicit expansion and implement everything yourself with MapFrom and ProjectTo parameters.

Comment: Actually I think it would work without materializing, because the result of the first ProjectTo would simply not have values for the excluded columns. And you'd have to check for null in the second step all the columns that could be not fetched. You might want to try it with LINQ and then with AM.